# Qual origem da palavra "adeus"?

Tags: origem-histórica, origem

Quando está se despedido de alguém, muitas vezes se fala:

- Tchau!
- Até logo!
- Até mais!
- Adeus!
- Etc.

Daí então fique pensando se "Adeus", teria alguma relação com Deus* por esta contido na palavra. Geralmente é muito forte se despedir de alguém assim. Dá uma impressão de que não verá nunca mais.

Qual origem da palavra "adeus"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adeus tem mesmo esse significado de uma despedida final.

A palavra é o encurtamento da frase "[A Deus vos recomendo](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/palavras/adeus/)" usada pelos padres há centenas de anos quando era comum que eles fossem convocados a comparecer ao leito de morte de alguém que estivesse quase partindo para "encomendar a alma" deste que, então, poderia ascender ao paraíso.

Com o passar do tempo foi encurtada e caiu no uso popular para despedidas, sendo usual para dar tchau a quem, geralmente, não vá se ver tão cedo novamente.

Comment: Legal Max, interessantíssimo. +1